# Overload method __eq __ ()

Tags: python

I program an educational game where the user has to reproduce a piece of factory offered by the computer.

To define a part one codes on the one hand the number of holes and on the other hand the thickness of line that there are on the diagonals ". For example, for an octagonal piece, `hole = [3,0,0,3]`, `line = [0,0,2,1]` encodes a part with 3 holes on the horizontal line, a line of thickness 2 on the vertical And a line of thickness 1 with 3 holes on the antidiagonal.
The center can be managed by several diagonals, the same part could be coded by `hole = [3,0,1,2]`, `trait = [0,0,2,1]` .

So I overloaded the `__eq __()` method like this :

```
    def __eq__(self, other):

    nouveau_trous = self.trous
    res=()
    for i in range(len(nouveau_trous)):
        if nouveau_trous[i] == 3 or nouveau_trous[i]==1:
            nouveau_trous[i]=nouveau_trous[i]-1
            retenue=1
            res=(nouveau_trous,self.traits,retenue)
    return res==other
```

("trous" = "holes" in french)

and when i try this :

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    p1=PieceModele(Canvas())
    p2=PieceUsine(Canvas())
    print(p1)
    print(p2)
    print(p1==p2)
    print(p1==p2)
```

I get this in the console :

```
[3, 0, 3, 3][1, 1, 1, 0]   8
[0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0]   8
False
True
```

I don't understand why i get True for the 2nd `print(p1==p2)` ...

Comment: What is `self.trou` defined as? Also did you try putting another pair of `print(p1); print(p2)` after the first comparison. I highly suspect that your equality operator is actually modifying the stored data, which would cause the problem

Comment: And if my previous assumption turns out to be right then the solution will be most likely to change `nouveau_trous = self.trous` to `nouveau_trous = self.trous[:]` or use the [copy library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Comment: add another `print(p1)` `print(p2)` after `print(p1==p2)`

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: i will try this ! ty

Comment: You're comparing tuples to, what I assume, are your classes. I'm not sure how you got `True` at any point.

Comment: Thank you all, my program is working !! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: How can i close the topic?

Comment: you are modifying data inside your comparison? that seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: as is overriding eq, in most cases.

Comment: My duty of the university requires me to use __eq__

Comment: You can close your own question either by deleting it, or answering it yourself.

Comment: You don't need to write **I program an educational game where the user has to reproduce a piece of factory offered by the computer.** at the beginning of every question. It has nothing to do with the question, and doesn't help the readers understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if my previous assumption turns out to be right then the solution will be most likely to change `nouveau_trous = self.trous to nouveau_trous = self.trous[:]` or use the copy library – UnholySheep

You're comparing tuples to, what I assume, are your classes. I'm not sure how you got True at any point. – 2rs2ts